# Extjs5 itemSelector not working when using bind

Tags: mvvm, bind, viewmodel, extjs5

I have a dataview that is getting its data from the bind

```
xtype:'dataview',
width:'100%',
loadMask: true,

bind:
{
    data:'{items}'     <--- this is a problem
},                              
tpl:Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
            '<tpl for=".">',                    
                '   <div class="icon-square">', 
                '       <img src="../images/{type}.png" />',
                '       <div class = "count-style">{count}</div>',
                '   </div>',                    
            '</tpl>'

),  
itemSelector: 'img',
//  itemSelector: 'div.icon-square', <-- this also does not work
    listeners:
               {                                
                    'itemclick':'onItemsSelect',                                                    
               }
}
```

The dataview works as expected and displays the data, but the itemselector is not triggering the itemclick event listener.

However if I replace the bind with an actual store, everything works as expected.

Does anybody have any idea of why it would not work only when I use the bind?

Answer (score 0):

For someone looking for solution, the below code change worked for me.

I created a view model to bind the data, instead of directly binding it.

```
viewModel:
{
    stores:
    {
        itemStore:
        {
            model:'RA.model.Item',              
            data:'{items}'
        }
    }
},
...
...
{

    xtype:'dataview',
    width:'100%',
    loadMask: true,                            
    bind:
    {
        store:'{itemStore}'
    },                              
    tpl:Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                '<tpl for=".">',                    
                    '   <div class="icon-square">', 
                    '       <img src="../images/{type}.png" />',
                    '       <div class = "count-style">{count}</div>',
                    '   </div>',                    
                '</tpl>'

    ),  
    itemSelector: 'img',
    listeners:
               {                                
                    'itemclick':'onItemsSelect',                                                    
               }
 }
```